# SDL and Xcode (SDL_image being ignored)

Tags: xcode, sdl, undefined-symbol, sdl-image

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/SDL_image, file was     
built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0  
0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386):
/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/SDL_image
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "_IMG_Load", referenced from:
    Image::Image(char const*)in main.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm getting the above error in my SDL project, and I am not for sure why. It was working the last time I ran the program (about three months ago) and now it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

get a 32bit version -- thats whats missing in this case.

- 'i386 = intel 32bit'
- 'x86_64 = intel 64bit'

Answer (score -1):

You apparently installed wrong version of SDL_image, if you are using a Mac OS X you should install [mac version](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/).